# top 画面で表示される buffers とは？

Tags: linux, ubuntu

top を起動すると、２行目ぐらいに、メモリの使用状況として、次のような行が表示されます。

```
 KiB Mem:   1017844 total,   742208 used,   275636 free,    20612 buffers
```

ここでいう、 `buffers` は何を表していますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示形式からLinuxと想像して。

buffersとその下のcached Memの数値はディスクキャッシュの使用量です。同じ領域がusedの値にも含まれますが、必要に応じて破棄されます。Windowsのタスクマネージャーでいうと「キャッシュ済み」の値に相当します。

ちなみにbuffersとcachedは、昔はそれぞれブロックデバイスレイヤーとファイルレイヤーのキャッシュだったそうですが、データ本体がcachedのほうに統一されたため、いまのbuffersはそれ以外のメタデータなどの量のようです。

Comment: すでに accept しましたが、一応、 unix から ubuntu へタグを付け替えました。

Answer (score 2):

参考までに、Ubuntu Linux 16.04(Linux kernel 4.4.0)の場合、top コマンドのバージョンは `procps-ng version 3.3.10` で、当該部分の表示は以下の様になっています。

```shell
KiB Mem :  2045332 total,   344444 free,   825764 used,   875124 buff/cache
```

top コマンドは procps パッケージに含まれていますが、同パッケージに free コマンドがあります。

```shell
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        2045332      825608      344600       87680      875124     1093132
```

free コマンドの出力の `buff/cache` カラムが top コマンドの `buff/cache` に対応しています(ソースコード上では同じ計算式を利用しています)。

**free(1)**

```shell
buffers
  Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)
cache
  Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and Slab in /proc/meminfo)
buff/cache
  Sum of buffers and cache
```

**proc(5)**

```shell
/proc/meminfo

  Buffers %lu
    Relatively temporary storage for raw disk blocks that shouldn't get tremendously large (20MB or so).
  Cached %lu
    In-memory cache for files read from the disk (the page cache). Doesn't include SwapCached.
  Slab %lu
    In-kernel data structures cache.
```